# rename file by md5 hash at jquery file upload

Tags: jquery-file-upload

i am useing [jquery file upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) (php) lastest ver,
i want rename a upload file by file md5 hash,
i have tried [this method](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/404)

```
md5(time().$file_name_only[0]).$extension ;
```

but only hash the time, how can i get the file md5 hash and rename by only md5?
( i dont want to hash of filename, i want hash of file )

thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
string md5_file ( string $filename [, bool $raw_output = false ] )
```